# Initializer 'init(_:formatter:)' requires that 'Double' inherit from 'NSObject'

Tags: swiftui

I created the following fooCurrency formatter that I am trying to use it in my code:

```
extension Formatter {
    
    static var fooCurrency: NumberFormatter {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        return formatter
    }
   
}

 Text(10.0, formatter: .fooCurrency)
```

I get the following message:

```
Initializer 'init(_:formatter:)' requires that 'Double' inherit from 'NSObject'
```

What does that mean and how can I format the number using my fooCurrency formatter?

Answer (score 3):

Objective-C based `NSNumberFormatter` expects an `NSNumber` **object**.

```
Text(10.0 as NSNumber, formatter: .fooCurrency)
```

Why not the native way?

```
Text(10.0.formatted(.currency(code: Locale.current.currencySymbol!)))
```

and

```
extension Formatter {
    
    static var fooCurrency: NumberFormatter {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        return formatter
    }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, seems that `Text(_:formatter:)` needs a `NSObject`.

Try this:

```
 Text(10.0 as NSObject, formatter: .fooCurrency)
```

Comment: as NSNumber also works.

Answer (score -1):

I have had a lot of fun and games with formatters and type casting. Typically I put an extension on the type to be converted to not have casting going on in my main code. eg.

```
extension Double {
    static let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    
    func asCurrencyString() -> String {
        Double.formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        let returnString = Double.formatter.string(from: self as NSNumber)
        if let returnString {
            return returnString
        } else {
            return "Default Value or error message...."
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let value = 10.0
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(value.asCurrencyString() )
        Text(10.0 as NSNumber, formatter: .fooCurrency)
    }
}
```